# How can I make items in GridView stick together?

Tags: android

I want something like this:

[image]

But so far, I get something like this:

[image]

Here is my main layout with gridview in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#404040" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="clickBack" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_type"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_arrow_back" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_back_main_main"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_type"
                android:background="#404040"
                android:text="戻る"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_big_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="カレンダー"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_passcode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/passcord_img" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_passcode_note"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_passcode"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ABCDEF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_passcode_note"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_passcode_circle1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_passcode_circle_pressed" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_passcode_circle2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_passcode_circle1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_passcode_circle_pressed" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_passcode_circle3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_passcode_circle2"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_passcode_circle_pressed" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_passcode_circle4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_passcode_circle3"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_passcode_circle_pressed" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_passcode_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="3" 
            >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is item layout to be inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border3" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txt_passcode_keypad"
        android:src="@drawable/border"
        android:text="ABCD" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_passcode_keypad"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_passcode_delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me solve this problem!

**Update:** I added stretchmode like Koma Yip said, and also changed width and height of Relativelayout in "item layout" to wrap_content, but it did not work. It become like this:

[image]

Comment: add android:stretchMode="columnWidth" in the gridview

Comment: @KomaYip I did as you said, but it did not work. I updated my post, please take a look ;)

Comment: changing width and height of Relativelayout in "item layout" to wrap_content will only make it follows content height and width, change them to "match_parent" seems more reasonable

Comment: Actually I also did that at first try, but i got same result

Comment: add android:verticalSpacing="0dp" android:horizontalSpacing="0dp" to gridview to give a last try

Comment: Turn on "Show layout bounds" in developers options and it would be easier to understand why there is a space between items.